# Prove that The set of Sentences over a theory $T$ is a Cartesian Closed Category

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory

i am sorry to bother but, I have doubts with this problem:

In some elementary theory $\;$ $T$ $\;$ consider the set $S=\{p,q,\ldots \}$ of sentences of $T$ as a preorder, with $p\leq q$ meaning "$p$ entails $q$" (i.e $q$ is a consequence of $p$ on the basis of axioms of $\;$ $T$). Prove that $\;$ $S$ is a Cartesian Closed Category, with product given by the conjunction and exponetial $q^{p}$ given by "$p$ implies $q$".

Actually, I don't Know how to start,  because  the terminal object must be a sentece in $S$ which is a consequence of every sentence of $S$, i do not know if I have a candidate for that in $S$.

If I have two sentences $p$ and $q$. How do i know that $p$ and $q$ are consequences of $p\wedge q$?

Any help or reference where i can read about the subject it would be great and I would be appreciate it.

Comment: Choose some tautology as terminal object. Since it is a tautology, it will be a consequence of every sentence.

Comment: Do you have any proof system at your disposal, which tells you what "entails" means? If so, you really ought to know already how to use that proof system to prove $p\land q \vdash_T p$ and $p\land q \vdash_T q$.

Comment: No i don't, that is all i hvae according the problem. That's why any reference would help me, in order to solve the problem.

Comment: x @Liddo: Then I'd have to say say you lack essential prerequisites for either doing the exercise or appreciating its solution. Any kind of introductory text in mathematical logic should work, at the basic level required here.

Comment: I knew it, that's why i was asking for any reference, so any suggestion for a good text.